# My anchor links do not work all the time

Tags: javascript, html

im losing it here. I working on this site and the menu link to differents anchors.. If im on another page the anchor link work properly but if im in the same page (home) do not work more than once.

I double check the urls and i think they are ok.

The live url is greencleansteamwash.com

The anchor links are Benefits, Services and Appointments

My code is something like this

```
<section id="benefits">
Content of benefits
</section>

<section id="plans">
Content of plans
</section>

<div id="book">
Content of booking
</section>

<ul class="nav-offcanvas">

<li><a href="http://greencleansteamwash.com/index.php#benefits">Benefits</a></li>

<li><a href="http://greencleansteamwash.com/index.php#plans">Services</a></li>

<li><a href="http://greencleansteamwash.com/index.php#book">Appointments</a></li>

</ul>
```

Comment: You're going to have to show us what you're talking about.

Comment: @Matthew sorry, im kind of new here. i've edit the question and add a sample code. The link url are absolutes bacause im using joomla url rewrite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the whole URL from the links, just leave the # part.

```
<li><a href="#benefits">Benefits</a></li>

<li><a href="#plans">Services</a></li>

<li><a href="#book">Appointments</a></li>
```

Comment: Hi Arturo, is working like that! Thanks for your answer. The issue is that the homepage is not the only page, if i put it like that when im in another page the anchor link will not work. Is this the only way? Do i have to make another menu for the other pages with the absolute url?

Comment: In the example i just put the anchor links but the menu also have other links to other pages.

Comment: Do you mean you're using the same exact menu in different document pages? Then I'm afraid I don't know how to do what you're looking for. Let me think about it for a moment...

Comment: I just create another menu for the inner sections, i mean other document pages. (I delete the previus comment to not confuse anyone)